# Missing point cloud from object - convert menu

Tags: objects, conversion

I miss the option *Convert* > *Pointcloud* in the object dropdown menu in the layout of Blender 3.3. Do I need to enable something in the settings or is this feature no longer available in the released version 3.3?

[image: screenshotofdropdownmenuBlen3.3]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this option was only integrated somewhere in version 2.91 (?) and was then removed again.

You can achieve the same result by simply selecting the entire geometry width with <kbd>A</kbd> in *Edit Mode*, then pressing <kbd>X</kbd> and selecting the option *Only Edges & Faces*.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in Blender 3.3.2 at least. Any attempt to remove edges and faces, in any method I tried in edit mode, will automatically remove vertices (points) if they are no longer connected to any edge.

Comment: So, I gave this another try, and it turns out it works. However, while in edit mode, the visualization and interactability with the points are not there. This means you need to switch back out into object mode to see the points after having done this. It is quite scary, as the experience makes you feel you have deleted your entire object.